# I try to put an elixir API (poison not phoenix) on docker but the it won't connect to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, elixir

So I built this API in Elixir that has different endpoints using Users, Products and Orders (using MongoDB:4.4). It works fine locally, but when I try to put it on Docker the connection to MongoDB which runs in another container always is refused and eventually fails. However, I connected to the MongoDB from the docker container using MongoDBCompass so it should have no problem. I think it might be a problem with the configuration but I have no Idea what to do anymore, I tried everything: using the Ip of the mongo docker container, using 127.0.0.1, using 0.0.0.0, using localhost. This is the Error:

```
users_service-elixir_app-1  | 12:06:41.705 [error] Mongo.Protocol (#PID<0.566.0>) failed to connect: ** (Mongo.Error) localhost:27017 tcp connect: connection refused - :econnrefused
users_service-elixir_app-1  |
users_service-elixir_app-1  | 12:06:41.723 [notice] Application api_test exited: exited in: ApiTest.Application.start(:normal, [])
users_service-elixir_app-1  |     ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
users_service-elixir_app-1  |         ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, :econnrefused}
users_service-elixir_app-1  |             (api_test 0.1.0) lib/services/publisher.ex:2: Api.Service.Publisher.start/2
users_service-elixir_app-1  |             (kernel 9.0.1) application_master.erl:293: :application_master.start_it_old/4
users_service-elixir_app-1  | 12:06:41.722 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.456.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no match of right hand value {error,econnrefused} in 'Elixir.Api.Service.Publisher':start/2 line 2 in application_master:init/4 line 142
users_service-elixir_app-1  | 12:06:41.723 [info] Application api_test exited with reason: no match of right hand value {error,econnrefused} in 'Elixir.Api.Service.Publisher':start/2 line 2
users_service-elixir_app-1  | Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,api_test,{bad_return,{{'Elixir.ApiTest.Application',start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{{badmatch,{error,econnrefused}},[{'Elixir.Api.Service.Publisher',start,2,[{file,"lib/services/publisher.ex"},{line,2}]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,293}]}]}}}}})
users_service-elixir_app-1  |
users_service-elixir_app-1  | Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
users_service-elixir_app-1 exited with code 1
```

Here is my Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml (yes, I also use rabbitmq but that's not the problem. Yet), config.exs, dev.exs, prod.exs.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM elixir:1.14

# Set environment variables
ENV MIX_ENV=prod TERM=xterm

# Create app directory and copy project files
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Install hex package manager and rebar
RUN mix local.hex --force && mix local.rebar --force

# Install dependencies and compile the project
RUN mix deps.get && mix deps.compile && mix compile

# Expose the desired port (3000)
EXPOSE 3000

# Start the server
CMD ["mix", "run", "--no-halt"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  elixir_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:     # Docker need to expose ports for you to access your app.
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - rabbitmq

  mongodb:
    image: mongo:4.4
    container_name: mongodb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
    ports:
      - 27017:27017

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
    ports:
      - 5672:5672
      - 15672:15672
```

config.exs:

```
use Mix.Config

import_config "#{config_env()}.exs"

# config :api_test,
# api_host: "localhost",
# api_port: 3000,
# api_scheme: "http",
# app_secret_key: "secret",
# jwt_validity: 3600,
# db_host: "localhost",
# db_port: 27017,
# db_db: "ski-online-shop",
# db_tables: [
# "users"
# ],
#
# routing_keys: %{
#     # User Events
#     "user_login" => "api.login.auth-login.events",
#     "user_logout" => "api.login.auth-logout.events",
#     "user_register" => "api.login.auth-register.events",
#     # Order Events
#     "order_added" => "api.order.add.events",
#     "pay_order" => "api.order.pay.events",
#     # Invoice Events
#     "invoice_added" => "api.invoice.add.events"
# },
# event_url: "guest:guest@localhost",
# event_exchange: "my_api",
# event_queue: "auth_service"
```

dev.exs and prod.exs (they are the same):

```
use Mix.Config
config :users_service, port:3000
config :users_service, database: "ski-online-shop"
config :users_service, pool_size: 2
config :users_service, :c, username: "user", password: "secret"

config :users_service, :db_config,
  name: :mongo,
  url: "mongodb://mongodb:27017/ski-online-shop"

config :amqp,
  connections: [
    myconn: [url: "guest:guest@localhost"]
  ],
  channels: [
    mychan: [connection: :myconn]
  ]
```

Comment: It really looks like MongoDB is not running / unreachable from your container. I know you've written you can connect from MongoDB Compass but it is a huge and complicated tool, not convenient for debugging. I'm reasonably sure that a simple 'telnet localhost 27017' will yield the same "Connection refused" that you have from your application.

Comment: It looks like you have exposed port `27017` to your host machine, but _not to the other containers in the docker-compose network_.  I think you need to define an `expose` section.  Best is to shell into the app running your Elixir app and verify that it can connect to the services it needs. I think this is more a docker-compose question than an Elixir one.
Also, this looks like an old Elixir config -- `use Mix.Config` has been deprecated for a while in favor of `import Config`

Comment: @Everett `expose` is just metadata, it's not required and the `ports` line should be enough.

Comment: What happens if you wait a bit for Mongo to startup, then restart your Elixir container? It could be that Mongo is not ready yet, and your app is trying to connect too early.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the mongodb container, you need to do a couple of things:

1. You do need to [expose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#expose) the ports on your MongoDB container in your docker compose file. This will allow you to connect to that service from other containers in the compose file.
2. You should use the name of the container as the mongo db host instead of `localhost`. In this case, set your `db_host` in your config files to `mongodb`. It looks like you might have done that already: `url: "mongodb://mongodb:27017/ski-online-shop"`